# Does git log pickup(show) commits associated with some branch or tag only?

Tags: git, git-log, git-reset

On running `git log --graph --oneline`, i see only commits(and there parent commits and there parent commits and so on) that are associated with some branch (local and origin) or tag.

That is if I reset on a branch to a previous commit and make a new commit, a new history line is created. Now if I merge the new local history line with origin, I see that the old history line is no more show in graph (unless the old history tip was tagged).

Even on querying for the entire repo logs seems to be not of help `git log --graph --oneline -all`

So, wondering if git log / graph pickups(shows) commits associated with some branch or tag only ? Could someone confirm or correct.

**Edit** - following answer from RomainValeri

From git docs:

> git-log - Show commit logs

and from actual observation and also answer from - RomainValeri

> git log --graph --oneline --all
>
> ## outputs all branch/tag histories

So is there any way to see the log of every commit (including dangling commits i.e those not associated with any branch/tag ) either with git log or any other alternate command/tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default it takes `HEAD`, but you could feed it any ref :

```
git log --graph --oneline
# outputs history backwards from HEAD

git log --graph --oneline branch-1
# outputs only branch-1 history

git log --graph --oneline --all
# outputs all branch histories
```

To address your comment below : for the case of `--all`, it doesn't mean it takes all commits, but all refs. So all the `refs/` dir will be explored (and `HEAD` also)

---

Edit after new scope :

To find lost (dangling) commits, use `fsck`

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

---

Finally, to link the two, you can nest commands.

```
git log --graph --oneline $(git fsck --lost-found | sed -E 's/dangling (tree|commit|blob|tag) //')
```

Comment: I actually meant --all too, because those commits seems to be not reachable on requesting for all graph too. Edited the question accordingly to broaden the scope.

Comment: gr8, `git fsck --lost-found` outputs a list, is there any better way to correlate them over the graph...  else using the above info seems quite difficult.

Comment: Your habit of taking criticism of your answers personally will not dissuade me from pointing out that your'e recommending a procedure that encourages practices that WILL lead inexperienced users into data loss.  Please stop doing things like that.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, Mark, we got to look at atleast two things here - (1)how to do something (is it possible), next (2) should we have to do it or not. Romain's answer and edit are perfect as they address the first part. To explore internal of a system one should not be dissuaded by the fact of side-effects. And appreciate your answer on why it should not be done.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I'm sorry if I gave you that impression, Mark, I welcome your criticism very much since you're one of the people here on SO whom I learned a lot from. I sincerely apologize. What's the data loss here?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I have to insist. A data loss with only read commands? How so? If it IS the case it's important to fix it, as I care a lot about not misinforming people. Don't you think so?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger No reference to gc whatsoever in the question, how should have I guessed it would later devolve into this? I'll happily chat about it with you if it can help defuse what seems to be a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: @RomainValeri - I think you're missing the point here.  OF COURSE the question didn't mention GC.  GC is relevant because it is running even though the user might not know about it - and in fact, if the user WERE to know about it, they probably wouldn't be asking how to make git use dangling commits.  There is no misunderstanding here. There is me pointing out that your answer is dangerous, and there is you, predictably, wanting to argue about it.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger No. I'm not arguing that my answer isn't dangerous. I read from you that it is, I give a lot of credit to what you think, so I try to understand why it is so. But why oh why the harshness? I'm trying to understand and amend, why can't you see it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear, but after your update it seems your main question is:

> So is there any way to see the log of every commit (including dangling commits i.e those not associated with any branch/tag ) either with git log or any other alternate command/tool.

The short (and still mostly accurate) answer is: not really.

If you have a dangling commit checked out (i.e. `HEAD` is detached and diverged from all refs) then you can see that history.  You can see history from the `reflogs` (a local record of where your repo's branches and `HEAD` have pointed in the past) to see a history that might not be reachable from any current ref.  And there are other similar exceptions.  You could even give git a specific commit ID to see the history leading to that commit.

But one way or other you do have to tell `git log` where to start its walk; it's not designed to go looking for dangling commits and starting a walk there.

Before I follow that to its conclusion - and the reason why "not really" is only *mostly* correct - I'd like to point out that if you have a commit that can't be reached by `--all`, then it's a matter of time before `gc` pulls the carpet out from under that commit - because as far as it can tell, such commits are unused.  Most `git` commands make the same assumption log does: that useful commits are reachable from refs (branches, tags, etc.), so even if you disabled `gc` to avoid such commits being deleted (not a good idea) you would still be forever trying to convince git to work with them.

So the only reasonable advice is, don't get in the habit of working in detached head state when authoring code that you want to persist; and if you are writing new changes you want to keep and then realize that you're in detached head, create a branch.

But for a *technically* more complete answer, I will note that git has one command whose job *is* to find dangling commits.  You could use `git fsck` to locate the unreachable objects (assuming they haven't already been cleaned up by `gc`), and then feed the resulting SHA ID values to `log`.  You might even be able to rig up a script to do it.

Comment: After some tests, I can amend "might even be able to rig up a script...' to "could rig up a script...'; but I still consider it a terrible idea, so I decline to share the notes on how I did it.

Comment: appreciate your point on GC. GC will cleanup things and it's not wise to rely on dangling commits for any purpose, be it a git log or some thing else.  But I don't see GC doing the cleanup always - I ran `$ git fsck --lost-found  | wc -l` output:18 ; then `git gc` then again `$ git fsck --lost-found  | wc -l` output: **18**. don't understand why GC is not removing the dangling stuff. any hints.

Comment: @samshers: dangling commits (and other unreachable objects) are removed by `git prune` when they're loose objects, or by a more complex pathway (repack-and-prune, mainly) when packed (but there are still more caveats here). The `git gc` command gives loose objects a grace period, default 14 days, before they get pruned, because Git commands that were started but haven't yet finished could be creating these loose objects right now. 14 days gives them time to finish up and get those objects into the graph.

Comment: So, first check if these are loose objects. If not, dig further into the pack stuff (which means looking up the `.keep` stuff as well). If so, check the timestamps on the loose object files, or use a gc or prune option that forces immediate pruning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is a bit ramble-y at this point as the question itself got a bit unfocused.  You started with `git log` and wandered into `git gc` territory. :-)

Git has *visible* references, such as `HEAD`, branch names, and tag names.  But Git also has *less-visible* references such as reflogs, and *invisible* references.  The last one is especially tricky:

- Ignoring `git worktree add` for a moment, let's look at the invisible references.  These are the entries in the index!  They refer directly to blob objects (only) but they keep those blobs alive for `git gc` purposes.
- Now let's throw in `git worktree add`.  When you add a work-tree, the added work-tree gets its own index, its own `HEAD`, and its own set of work-tree-specific special references (`ORIG_HEAD`, `git bisect` refs, and so on).  The `git gc` and `git fsck` commands must inspect all of these references.  In Git 2.5, when `git worktree` first went in, they didn't!  This went unfixed until Git 2.15.  The result of this was that when `git gc` ran, it could throw away data being used in some of the added work-trees: objects stored only in an added work-tree's index, or commits reachable only from an added work-tree's detached HEAD, were missed, and could be GCed after the prune expiry (default = 14 days).

You can have `git log` walk the reflogs with `-g`, or you can have it walk all the normal references with `--all`.  However, the `--all` flag only looks at *this* work-tree's work-tree-specific refs.  Meanwhile `git fsck` and `git gc` must look at all references, including the reflogs and the invisible and per-work-tree references.  If you have a Git between 2.5 and 2.15, this is broken, so beware of using added work-trees for too long.  (I was bitten by this particular bug myself.  Fortunately the added work-tree had nothing important in it.)

Exercise (discoverable without peeking at the source): is `refs/stash` per-work-tree, or global?  (I don't know the answer myself.)

Comment: Global :-) Just tried it from another worktree and `git log refs/stash` outputs the same from both. Right?

Comment: @RomainValeri Yep, that's the test. Can be applied to each ref to find out which way it gets treated.

Comment: I'll go further and shamelessly state that I just discovered the mere existence of `refs/stash`. I nearly stopped using the stash myself, I prefer to temporarily commit on branches themselves, but I often have to help coworkers who burned themselves with it. Not that I would consider it bad practice or anything, I don't have an opinion yet, still trying to have a better picture for now.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to see the log of every commit (including dangling commits i.e those not associated with any branch/tag )

Usually adding `--reflog` to your command is enough to see every commit you've made or abandoned in the last month or so, regardless of whether it's in any current history.

It's possible to generate and abandon commits without making reflog entries, but it's harder to imagine why you'd be hunting for these.  The way to find all the ghost tips, the ones `--reflogs` doesn't reach because they were abandoned long ago or were generated by homegrown workflows/scripts that think they don't need no stinking reflogs is

```
git fsck --connectivity-only --unreachable --no-dangling
```